# values not persisting in dropdown of optional block - jelly/jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I have the following in config.jelly:

```
<f:block>
    <table style="width:100%" id="rpmParameters-generic">
        <j:set var="rpmParameters" value="${instance.rpmParameters}" />
        <f:optionalBlock name="rpmParameters" checked="${rpmParameters != null}"
            title="Mandatory parameter for rpm/msi/zip artifacts only" help="/plugin/artifactory/help/common/help-rpmParameters.html">
            <input type="hidden" name="stapler-class" value="org.jfrog.hudson.util.RpmParameters" />
            <f:entry title="Operating System">
                <select class="setting-input" name="operatingSystem"
                    value="${rpmParameters.operatingSystem}">
                    <option value="rhel5">rhel5</option>
                    <option value="linux">linux</option>
                    <option value="solaris">solaris</option>
                    <option value="windows">windows</option>
                </select>
            </f:entry>
            <f:entry title="Architecture">
                <select class="setting-input" name="architecture"
                    value="${rpmParameters.architecture}">
                    <option value="i386">i386</option>
                    <option value="x86_64">x86_64</option>
                    <option value="no arch">no arch</option>
                </select>
            </f:entry>
        </f:optionalBlock>
    </table>
</f:block>
```

The problem is that the checkbox for optional block persist when I hit save but for some reason the dropdown values of operating system and architecture don't persist in the UI after I save and reopen configuration.

Any idea why ?

Comment: Why are you not using [dropdownListBox](https://jenkins-ci.org/maven-site/jenkins-core/jelly-taglib-ref.html#form:dropdownListBlock) which has `selected` attribute?

Comment: wow, I couldn't find that tag lib reference in all this time. Would have saved me so much time. So I can't use dropdown. 

Actually I got it to work using choose-when-otherwise but I didn't like that approach

Comment: @Raghuram - can you give me an example of how to use dropdownlistbox to persist the dropdown choice ?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ui-samples-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/jenkins/plugins/ui_samples/DropdownList/index.jelly) is one example.   Alternately you could also see how you can add `selected` attribute to your above code similar to [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/rake-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/rake/Rake/config.jelly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well turns out I was doing most things right. The issue was having a

```
<f:options
```

for every option in dropdown. Something like this worked.

```
<select class="setting-input" name="artifactKey" id="genericArtifactKeys-${s.url}">
                                                <f:option value="nuget" selected="${instance.artifactoryKey =='nuget'}">nuget</f:option>
                                                <f:option value="zip" selected="${instance.artifactoryKey =='zip'}">zip</f:option>
                                                <f:option value="msi" selected="${instance.artifactoryKey =='msi'}">msi</f:option>
                                                <f:option value="rpm" selected="${instance.artifactoryKey =='rpm'}">rpm</f:option>
                            </select>
```